# Issue with managed array in C++/CLI

Tags: arrays, winforms, visual-c++

I'm  a c++ programmer and I'm having some issue with managed array. I'll explain what i mean. I'm using Visual Studio to code a Windows Form to handle a device.
I need to plot datas from a MCU connected to my PC thru a serial port. To save the values incoming from serial port, I'm using an array like that:

```
array<double, 1>^ datas = gcnew array<double, 1>(ndatas);
array<Byte, 1>^ byteDatas = gcnew array<Byte, 1>(2*ndatas);
```

where `ndatas` is the number of values of my series and `byteDatas` is the array where I will save the bytes that compose every value. Every value is made by 2 bytes.
After that, I will fill this array like this:

```
for(int i = 0; <=ndatas; ) {  
    if(bytes = serialPort1->BytesToRead>=2) {
       datas[i] = getData(serialPort1, byteDatas, i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

The funcion `getData` is this one:

```
double getData(serialPort^ sp, array<Byte,1> data, int i) {      
  union Level {
     char L[2];
     signed short level;
  } lvl;  
  sp->Read(data, i, 2);  
  for(int j = 0; j<=2; j++) {
    lvl.L[j]= data[i+j];
  }
  return safe_cast<double>(lvl.level/100.00);
}
```

This function is on another .cpp file, so I had to use the variable `SerialPort`.
Everything goes like charm. If I try to use a MessageBox to display my datas, I can see how my array is correctly filled with the right values.
My next step to do, is to plot this data on a pictureBox using drawLine. But I really can't cause half of the values of the array `datas` are set to 0. For istance, if my series has 100 values, I can draw only the first values with the right amplitude. The other are represented, of course, as a horizontal line of zeroes.
To find this out, I have used a for cycle like that.

```
for(int i = 0; i<=datas->Length; i++) {
   MessageBox::Show(Convert::ToString(datas[i]+" " + Convert::ToString(i+1));
}
```

just to be sure from when I will find the problem.
The strange part of this one is that, if I put the same MessageBox line of code under

```
datas[i] = getData(serialPort1, byteDatas, i);
```

I can display all of values without zeroes.
I'm stuck, and I don't know how to get rid of this problem. I hope I can find a little help to overcome this annoying issue.
I wish everything is crystal clear and I would like to thank everyone will give me a feedback.
Cheers,
Emiliano

Comment: This is not the real code.  `for(int i = 0; <=ndatas; ) { ` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Yep, I missed this part. Out of the `if`, I coded `i++`. Thanks for reply

Comment: The part `; <= ndatas;` still is an syntax error.  Missing `i`?

Comment: Edited the main post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do call `getData`, you're getting a valid value.

But `BytesToRead` goes down as you read data.  At some point it drops below 2, and the rest of the `for` loop does nothing.

You might need to save where you are in the array when you run out of data, and when more serial data arrives, continue filling in the array from where you left off.

Plus, of course, right now you appear to be putting every data value into element 0 of the array, because you never increment `i`.

Also, you're reading each data point at index `i`, which means that you overwrite the second byte from the previous sample.

There's no need for `safe_cast`, the result of the division is already a `double`.  And even if you needed a conversion, `safe_cast` isn't appropriate, since none of these data types are polymorphic.

Furthermore, your use of the `union` causes undefined behavior.

Finally, you're in C++.  So why are you using what is probably the worst designed serial port API Microsoft ever made?  This is C++.  Calling Win32 APIs is easy, just `#include <windows.h>` and go, no p/invoke needed.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your suggestion are very appreciated! My MCU works only if a line command is written, then it stops sending datas. So, I think it's quite safe using `BtR`. I just used safe_cast cause I'm trying to convert from int to double and the compiler tells me I may lose some information. It seems quite strange, but the code works as expected. I even tried `memcpy`instead of `union` and I manage to get the same result. By the way, if the MCU fires 100 values, my `datas`is filled with 100 right values. But I can't use them, only the half, out of the loop which I'm getting them in.